# How can I use "AND" and "OR" in SQLiteDatabase.delete(…) method?

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause, sql-delete

I am using the following code for deleting some rows from my table in Android:

```
sqliteDb.delete("MYTABLE", "Tel" + " = ?", new String[] { "1" });
```

How can I call this method for the following 3 Query types?

```
Delete from MYTABLE where Tel = 1 OR Tel = 2

Delete from MYTABLE where Tel = 1 AND Number = 2

Delete from MYTABLE where Tel = 1 OR Number = 2
```

Comment: you can use `.exeSQL()` method instead

Comment: `sqliteDb.delete("MYTABLE", "Tel = ? OR Tel = ?", new String[] { "1", "2" });`

Comment: using `.exeSQL()` is a bad practice, sql injection can be done.

Comment: @hotveryspicy why `.exeSQL()` is a bad practice?

Comment: @breceivemail http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection

Comment: Horse crap :)  .exeSQL() is perfectly appropriate for the vast majority of use cases.  IMHO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can do like.

```
sqliteDb.delete("MYTABLE", "Tel" + " = ? OR Tel" + " = ?", new String[] { "1",  "2" });
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, something like:

```
String tableName = "MYTABLE";
String where = "Tel = ? or Number = ?";
String[] whereArgs = {"1", "2"};
```

How you'd choose one version of where (`"Tel = ? or Number = ?"`) vs. a different version (`"Tel = ? AND Number = ?"`) is completely up to you :)